# ASP.NET MVC 2 Reload pages without refresh and keep URL changing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am creating a project using ASP.NET MVC. I want to show content of pages in the placeholder without refreshing the page, something like ajax but WITH the URL changing, How can I accomplish this ?

Thank you for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the jQuery BBQ plugin (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) with great success. This and the jQuery Templating engine would be great for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6):

If you change the url of the browser this will automatically perform a redirect and refresh the entire page. You could use the hash sign (`#`) which doesn't trigger a refresh. For example if you change `/home/index#foo` to `/home/index#bar` the page won't refresh but you could send an AJAX request behind the scenes to update some placeholder.