# ASP.NET MVC 2 Reload pages without refresh and keep URL changing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC 2 Reload pages without refresh and keep URL changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530272/asp-net-mvc-2-reload-pages-without-refresh-and-keep-url-changing)

Hi guys,

I am creating a project using ASP.NET MVC. I want to show content of pages in the placeholder without refreshing the page, something like ajax but WITH the URL changing, How can I accomplish this ? I have made it throught AJAX but url is static and in contentplaceholder it is showing page with masterpage. Any ideas ?

Thank you for your responses

Comment: @nice qu. something that I was thinking to research for a long time.